# How long do I have to stay out of Singapore before returning for another tourist visit?

Tags: visas, singapore, indonesian-citizens, repeat-visits

I am an Indonesian citizen. On May 29th I've returned from a 30-day trip to Singapore. I plan to visit Singapore again on the 13th of June for another 30 days.

Would this cause any problems at the border?

Comment: What's your citizenship? How long have you been in Singapore? Did you return to your country of origin or just to a neighbouring country? Are you actually planning to do tourism?

Comment: Indonesia, 23 days before my visit and the visit 30 days later Inclusive plan visit johor and will go back to my country of Singapore.yes I do as tourist

Comment: Please add all this to your question (through the “edit” link) as I think it might be relevant. But to clarify: You are from Singapore or Indonesia?

Comment: I'm from Indonesia